# How can I get a JavaScript stack trace in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, stack-trace

I ran an HTML file on Firefox and I want to debug it.

I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> and then I got a menu of Console/HTML/CSS/Script.

How I can find the stack of the program?

Comment: [Get firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or alternatively use Chrome which has great debugging tools built in.

Comment: The F12 and the "Console/HTML/CSS/Script" suggest that he's running Firebug already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Detailed info on Firebugs Console API is here: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.trace.28.29
the console.trace() function might be what youre looking for

Comment: Note that `console.trace()` works with the built-in Firefox Web Console (`Ctrl+Shift+K`).

Comment: It is the year 2020. Firebug no longer exists. I ask this question again.